# Unable to access Choice Parameter selected values inside next "extended choice parameter" value (groovy script)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops, jenkins-groovy

step1 - Declared "appname" as choice parameter with 10 values.(single select)
step2 - To get the latest artifact of the above appname, used "artifact_name" as extended choice param
        with 'max count-10' delimeter as ','

```
    So the "artifact_name" values , i mean the last artifacts like 10 should be displayed inside 
    "single select" list box of "artifact_name"


    -> Groovy Source script for "artifact_name" value is below.

    def filter= "${params.appname}"  //Not able to get above declared variable to new variable and use it dynamically in below url to filter the artifacts)
    def con = def connection = new URL( "https://hostname/artifactory/source-artifactory/$filter/?list&deep=1&listFolders=0&mdTimestamps=1&includeRootPath=0" )
    .openConnection() as HttpURLConnection


    So am not able to access the "appname" value and assign it to a new variable like "def filter = "${params.appname}"  and use the new variable in connection url for every application name to get the artifacts. S
```

Hardcoded value working but i have 10 apps can't create ten jobs with hardcoded values.

Comment: Can you share the complete code, so as to understand the scope of the variables.

Comment: Hi @salsinga, Actually "appname" is declared as choice parameter and "artifact_name" is extended choice param with groovy code to retrieve values and place in list.

Comment: couldn't get the "appname" value and use it in groovy source of variable "artifact_name" as shared above.

Comment: i meant their type- def or env

Comment: appname-choice parameter(single select)   artifact_name- Basic parameter(single select)

Comment: @salsinga can you help me with this? much appreciated.